# Logon scripts from linux to linux

Tags: group-policy, logon-scripts

I have some linux desktop boxes and I would like to launch different logon scripts depending on which user logs to each computer.
I would like to manage it from a centralized place, like windows gpo in active directory.

Which opensouce/GNU solution are you using for that purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: Are these shell logins? Ssh? Gnome?

Comment: I would like it to be executed when GDM let's the user in.

I was also thinking with this purposes:

- information retrieve on login (hw and software)
- software deployment
- message displays
- security patches
- sudoers maintenance
- web certificates deploy


May be i'm wrong, but it's what AD does with GPO , and I would like to do it without the AD.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at something like Puppet or Chef for the configuration management aspect of GPO. You can use this to do all the software deployment, patching, sudoers configuration.

You might want to look at PAM to do some things when people log in, but mostly, something like /etc/profile or /etc/bashrc assuming all your users use bash.